# What's the mathematical name for a 3D object with 8 vertices such that no four points are on the same plane?

Tags: geometry, terminology, 3d

Is there a name for a 3D object with 8 vertices such that no four points are on the same plane?

Comment: Probably no generic name exists for that.

Comment: this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedron ?

Comment: @Thomas No, an Octahedron has 8 faces but only 6 vertices...

Comment: An interesting thing is that, as all faces must be triangles, we have $V-E+F=2$ and $3F=2E$ which with $V=8$ yields $E=18$ and $F=12$. It also follows (pigeonhole principle) that at least one vertex has at least $5$ edges. However, one can think of many 3D shapes with those exact numbers.

Comment: I don't know if this has a name. This kind of shape can occur if you start with a 3d lattice grid, with cuboid cells, and then distort it some way. This can be problematic since four points that previously defined a shared face where two cuboids touch is no longer planar. An extra diagonal edge needs to be added to the face, and that should be the same for both former cuboids otherwise you get a tetrahedron gap between them or a tetrahedron where they overlap.